# How to force exit man buffer preventing jumping into *Messages* buffer

Tags: exit, man

I am using `emacs` to read man pages.

```bash
macsman() {
    emacsclient -nw -e "(let ((Man-notify-method 'bully)) (man \"$1\"))"
}
alias man=macsman
```

---

```lisp
(define-key Man-mode-map "q" 'save-buffers-kill-emacs)
```

While man buffer is opened, when I press `q` it usually exits.

> It is bound to `If the current frame has no client, kill Emacs itself using ‘save-buffers-kill-emacs’.`

After running ex: `man ls` and pressing "`q`" in order to exit and get back to my shell, I find myself in `*Messages*` buffer, than pressing `q` again opens the man page again, and finally pressing `q` exits `emacs`. What may be the reason of this?

Would it be possible to exit right away by preventing opening `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: Sorry, its bound to `save-buffers-kill-emacs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just popping in and out for the man page, you don't need the `save-buffers-kill-emacs` because there are no buffers to save. Just unconditionally kill Emacs.

```
Command: kill-emacs &optional exit-data

This command calls the hook kill-emacs-hook, then exits the Emacs 
process and kills it.

If exit-data is an integer, that is used as the exit status of the       
Emacs process. (This is useful primarily in batch operation; see Batch   
Mode.)

If exit-data is a string, its contents are stuffed into the terminal 
input buffer so that the shell (or whatever program next reads input)  
can read them.

If exit-data is neither an integer nor a string, or is omitted, that 
means to use the (system-specific) exit status which indicates 
successful program termination.
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was  just popping in and out for the man page. Seems like `kill-emacs` also kill the emacs daemon, would it be possible to keep emacs daemon running

Comment: No but I believe there's a *restart if stopped* switch for the daemon.

Comment: Does restart completely kills the emacs daemon?

Comment: The idea is that if Emacs detects that the daemon has been stopped, it restarts it.